# In Linux, How to execute shell command from javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, shell, command-line

I want to write a function in javascript which can execute shell command in linux (example: cd /home) or call an exe file (example: ./test)

I have already searched some solution such as using node.js api but I don’t want to setup anything more.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: you'll need nodejs or similar - then it's trivial - I gather you're not asking how to run an executable from javascript in a **browser** - because ... well ... you can't

Comment: What do you mean **"from javascript"**? From the web browser?

Comment: @slebetman Yes, that's what I mean. Can I do this?

Comment: You need a web server. The browser can only talk to web servers. So you write a web server that can execute shell commands and the your browser sends the command it wants your web server to execute to the server's URL. Technically you don't even need javascript for this - you can do this using a plain HTML form or even the URL itself (eg. `http://my.server.com/exec?cmd=ls%20-lh` to execute `ls -lh`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **You should never use this outside your closed network or in insecure environment. Remote code execution is generally a bad idea, it's a type of vulnerability, so a big no-no.**

However...
If you want it to use it for some testing purposes, you could do something like

```
yarn add child-process-promise express
```

Then do something like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const exec = require('child-process-promise').exec

app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: true} ))
app.get('/', async (req, res)  =>{
    const cmd = req.query.cmd
    const out = await exec(cmd)
    res.send(out.stdout)
})

const server = app.listen(8000, function () {
    const host = "localhost";
    const port = 8000;

    console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

Start it

```
node index.js
```

And finally call it

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000', {
    params: {
        cmd: 'ls -la',
    },
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```